# import multiple components and interfaces using commonJS require

Tags: node.js, typescript

How do I import multiple objects/components/interfaces using the least amount of `require()` syntax? For example, the es6 code has this,

```
import express, {Express, Request, Response} from "express";
```

Is there something similar I can do using the `require()` module? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
const express = require("express");
const {Express, Request, Response} = express;
```

If you don't need the **`express`**, you can do

```
const {Express, Request, Response} = require("express");
```

Choose the one that suits you better